# How can I install the sound modules

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu-16.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS bash on Windows 10. When I have installed a command line music player, it couldn't play any track - `Error: unable to play audio.`

The command `aplay -l` shows `aplay: device_list268: no soundcards found.` So it looks like I need to install the sound modules. How can I do it? I have tried this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-restricted-modules-uname -r linux-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-restricted-modules-4.4.0-43-Microsoft
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-restricted-modules-4.4.0-43-Microsoft'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-restricted-modules-4.4.0-43-Microsoft'
```

Also, when running the command `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0403]'` it shows the following:

```
pcilib: Cannot open /proc/bus/pci
lspci: Cannot find any working access method.
```

Comment: First I would try upgrading your kernel, the new kernel might just include the driver.  Your code dump suggests you are runing kernel version 4.4 however 4.16.5 is the current version.

Comment: just a FYI, it might not be possible.  WSL is still beta and might not have the ability to pass audio.  I would suspect as the platform matures, more and more features will work.

Comment: @Keltari, I don't think it is beta any more.

Comment: There is an uservoice page [link](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/14017329-sound-card-support). You may see a green badge if this feature is added.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://askubuntu.com/q/1028324/250300

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible currently under WSL since you don't get access to that part of the Kernel.

WSL uses Pulse Audio so if you have a player that uses that, it should work.

For more information on this issue and possible workarounds, see:

https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1200